# Oracle SOA client authentication by certificate

Tags: oracle, soa, wcf-security, esb, suite

Is it possible to configure Oracle SOA composite service for authentication by client certificate? For instance, we have Oracle composite service and WCF service. Composite service should be ensured that only clients with valid certificate have access. How does it should be configured?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure 2-way SSL on weblogic server which hosts Oracle SOA suite. This ensures that only certified clients can make use of your service.

Other option is to use OWSM policies which can be configured for each service. Here is a good link to start with 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10226/soacompapp_secure.htm